# How to set android emulator-specific log level

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android emulator writes logs on stderr. For example when I start the emulator, it writes this:

```
emulator: INFO: boot completed
```

Or when I take a screenshot, this:

```
emulator: INFO: ScreenCapturer.cpp:67: Screenshot from renderer
```

How can I set log level on these logs, or suppress them completely?